# Change hydraulic block to gas block Simscape

Tags: matlab, simulink, modeling, simscape

[image]I am creating a Simscape gas model where I need to use 3 way directional valves. Unfortunately there are no directional valves in the gas library. I used the 3 way directional valves from the hydraulic library but I get dashed red lines when I try to connect the valve to the other gas components. Is there a way of converting a hydraulic block to a gas block in Simulink/Simscape?

Edit: Added image of model

Comment: If you show the relevant segment of your model, and your expected inputs/outputs, then we may be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: @Wolfie I have added an image of the model. The olive olive coloured valves and lines are the ones that I am trying to convert to gas components. Thanks

Comment: Well in its current form, it's like you're trying to solder a wire into the end of a hose pipe, then inflate a party balloon with the resulting flow. Simscape blocks work by balancing physical equations, just because you have a 3-way valve in one block type, you can't use it to control something of a completely different nature. You need to use one of two methods: **1.** combine simscape blocks of the same type to achieve more complicated systems / functions. **2.** Convert into a Simulink signal (using `PS-P` block), write some numerical logic, convert back to a physical Simscape signal

Comment: @Wolfie Thank you. Creating my own blocks solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Wolfie has indicated, you can't connect a hydraulic component to a gas component, they are two completely different physical domains. To recap and add to what your options are:

1. Combine Simscape blocks to create your own model of a directional valve in the gas domain. There is an example of that in the [Pneumatic Actuation Circuit](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/examples/pneumatic-actuation-circuit.html) example:

[image]

2. Use the [Simscape language](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/lang/what-is-the-simscape-language.html) to create your own block of a gas directional valve.
3. Use [Simulink to Physical Signal](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/simulinkpsconverter.html) and [Physical Signal to Simulink](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/pssimulinkconverter.html) blocks to interface your Simscape model to your model of the gas directional valve created in Simulink. Probably not as good a solution (even though it's potentially easier), as you lose the acausality that Simscape provides by going back into Simulink.